# How can I trick my system into thinking I have installed a program (gdc)

Tags: alias

G-WAN uses gdc to compile D scripts.
I'm having problems with gdc for D2 and would like to use dmd instead (They're both D compilers).

So what I've done is used `alias gdc="dmd"` I can now compile D2 code by calling `gdc hello.d` but G-WAN still tells me `To use D (*.d) scripts, install 'gdc'`

Can I trick it into using dmd without having access to the source code?

Comment: One word of warning  to anyone reading this: if there are any `version` statements in your code for some reason (even though it only allows gdc) then this won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to create a script in your $PATH with the name `gdc` and call dmd in it.

For example: $HOME/bin/gdc

Contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Enter the dmd compile command below
# $@ are your command line arguments
dmd $@
```

Make it executable: `chmod +x $HOME/bin/gdc`